# post on facebook says: "Graph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to work with the **publish_actions** with my webapp. I am using php sdk v.5

I have this piece of code:

<...>

```
    if ( isset($accessToken) ) {

    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);

    /* I try to post something on my wall here: */

    $params["message"] = 'test';
    $params["link"] = 'http://www.lucarossi.info';
    $params["picture"] = 'test-image.jpg';
    $params["description"] = 'test';
    $access_token = $accessToken;

    try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $params, $access_token);
    } 

    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }


    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode(); 
    echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];

}
```

<...>

but I receive the following message: "Graph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

I have requested the publis_actions features on facebook dev and **they are enabled**. Anyway, when I am trying to login on facebook through my app, I have the message "This does not let the app post to Facebook."

I am trying to figure out what's the problem, but I'm not even sure if it is a php issue, or permission issue or whatever.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Access Token most likely does not include `publish_actions`. Test the Token in the debugger and make sure `publish_actions` shows up: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

`publish_actions` needs to get reviewed by Facebook, else you can only use it as user with a role in the App. Not sure what you mean with "requested `publish_actions` on Facebook dev and they are enabled", but you need to set it in the scope parameter in your login process. Try with a user who is admin/dev/tester of your App.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. The publish_actions are reviewed and enabled. That's what the application "review" summary page says on the facebook developer portal. Anyway I figure as a developer, so I should be able to post with my account in both cases. I am checking the token part. Maybe the problem is there. Thank you!

Comment: are you sure that facebook approved the permission? they will not approve it if it did not even work while testing your app. there is a big difference between login review approval and authorization.

Comment: anyway, if you are trying as developer, there´s something wrong with your login code. use the link from my answer to test your token.

Comment: I have this:
publish_actions:
Provides access to publish feed posts, Open Graph stories, achievements, scores and other activity detailed in Publishing Permissions.

Comment: where exactly do you have that? again, test your access token in the debugger.

Comment: On the review page.  I'm pretty sure I'm fine on the facebook part. I'm gonna check the token part. Thank you!

Comment: it does not matter what you see on the review page (at least not for testing as developer of the app), your login process is important, and the user access token.

Comment: found the trick: that was missing: $permissions = ['email', 'publish_actions']; Thank you for your support!

Comment: that´s in the very first sentence of my answer, kind of ;)